# Is there a way to restrict the element from dropping over the boundary area - jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have developed drag and drop using jquery ui. So if i drag n drop the element over the boundary of the drop box it still takes in the element so is there any way to restrict the boundary region for the drop ?
Screenshot : http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/5662/borderk.jpg

Comment: Most likely yes, which answers your question, but without seeing any code related to the problem.. it's hard to say how that can be achieved.

Comment: i tried pasting the code in jsfiddle but the drop region doesn't seem to show up properly.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your current code you have one element that has a background image.

If you change your html and css to something like this and use the `db-inner` as the drop area, then this should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/xTYPP/

HTML:

```
<div id="DropBox">
    <div id="db-inner"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#DropBox {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #e1e1e1 url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/70') no-repeat top left;

    padding: 10px;
}

#db-inner {
    width 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 1px dashed #777;
}
​
```

**To simplify:** Parent element adds padding that restricts the inner element dimensions which are defined to be `100%`

**The idea** is that `#db-inner` would be the drop box element and `#DropBox` is an extra wrapping element that holds your background image and it just happens to be bigger than the dropbox area.

Comment: still have the problem :(  http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/3637/dragu.jpg  code - http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/

Comment: @user1184100 Somewhat inconsistently it seems like the center of the icon is basically what restricts it so it always enables you to stick it half way out of the container.. I tried this, but I just made adding of the icons into the box somewhat harder :D ( The inner edges of the dashed container has area where you cant drop them ) http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/DTYEB/1/ I'm not sure if I know how to fix this :/

Comment: thank you Lollero :) will try to tweak ur idea or find an alternate

Comment: @user1184100 I think you might want to deselect my answer as the correct one and see if other people have ideas. I'm quite positive that this can't be solved with just html and css.. ( The "solution" that I had is pretty much as far as you can go. ) Some changes to the js would have to be made and I just don't have the cojones for that...